Calling QDialog.reject() has no effect - why? How do I close my dialog when certain conditions are met?
Calling QDialog.reject() has no effect. What am I missing?
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QDialog, QVBoxLayout
class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('MyDialog created')
        self.setWindowTitle('My Dialog')
        button = QPushButton('Close')
        button.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(button)
        self.reject()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton("Press Me!")
        button.clicked.connect(self.show_dialog)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def show_dialog(self):
        d = MyDialog()
        rv = d.exec()
        if rv == QDialog.Accepted:
            print('Dialog accepted')
        else:
            print('Dialog rejected')


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()

When running the program, the dialog shows up and I can press "Close". The return value is 'Accepted'. I would expect the dialog would either not show or close right away, and that the return value should be 'Rejected'
What am I missing?

You're calling QDialog::reject before the dialog has even been shown.  At that point the result code will be QDialog::Rejected.  But you then show the dialog and wait for the next result code.  What are you actually trying to achieve by calling QDialog::reject in the constructor?

@G.M. That makes sense. When the dialog is opened I check if some condition is met (files loaded). If not the user is prompted to do so - in a new dialog. If the user cancels dialog (file load operation) I want the first dialog to close too.

@TroelsBlum Reimplement exec so that it includes the additional logic: i.e. if the files aren't loaded, run the other dialog, and if it's cancelled, return QDialog.Rejected; otherwise, return super().exec().

Thanks. I decided to go for another solution, that does not require rejecting in init

@TroelsBlum The point is that rejecting in the __init__ is completely pointless and inappropriate to begin with, especially if you need the user to interact with it, because at that point the dialog has not been shown yet (and it shouldn't). The __init__ should also normally return immediately, as soon as possible, then the dialog is eventually shown by using exec() (or open()).
